# Best way to scaffold a backend directory structure shared among different projects

Tags: node.js, git, api, scaffolding, hapi.js

My backend right now it's a well-modularized directory structure and it's a RESTful API server. I'm using Hapi.

The problem that I'm facing is that I need to create another backend project and I'd like to reuse all the common functionality between the 2 projects, I'd like to reuse the same code base, the same scaffold.

I have two solutions:

- Create a separate git repository for the new project and just copy the directory structure. The main problem with this approach is that I'm duplicating code. If I need to modify this common code base, I need to modify 2 projects, and this is a maintenance nightmare.
- Use the same git repository for both projects. Luckily, Hapi has the concept of a connection. Each connection it's bound to a different socket and has its own routes and stuff, so it's very easy to just configure a different connection for the other server. During the bootup I could choose which connection to use, an approach similar to this:

  ```
  $ NODE_ENV=development node server.js --connection mobile  
  $ NODE_ENV=development node server.js --connection web
  ```

  This is the most cleaner and elegant way to accomplish my objective, but it has a major disavantage for me, git flow, because I'm not an expert on this field. I'd need to maintain 3 branches: `base`, `mobile` and `web`. Depending on which branch you are, you see different files. For example:

  ```
  .  
  ├─ base  
  │  └─ common.js  
  ├─ mobile  
  │  └─ file1.js  
  └─ web
     └─ file2.js
  ```

  If the current branch is `mobile`, you'll see the `base` and the `mobile` directories.
  If the current branch is `web`, you'll see the `base` and the `web` directories.
  If the current branch is `base`, you'll see the `base` directory.

  From a point of view of software versioning is this acceptable? When deploying to production I simply to push the branch I'd like to upload and on the remote server checkout to that branch and start the server. For example:

  To start the **mobile** server:

  *local*

  ```
  $ git push production-server mobile
  ```

  *production server*

  ```
  $ git checkout mobile
  $ NODE_ENV=production node server.js --connection mobile
  ```

  To start the **web** server:

  *local*

  ```
  $ git push production-server web
  ```

  *production server*

  ```
  $ git checkout web
  $ NODE_ENV=production node server.js --connection web
  ```

  So far, so good. Now suppose that I need to modify the base and apply the changes to the branches `mobile` and `web`. I've been reading this article, [merge vs rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/) and doing some tests, and I've seen in SourceTree that rebasing is just what I need. Visually it's more cleaner and conceptually it's ok, rebasing `base` into `mobile` and `web` just updates them to the lastest `base` changes.

  With this approach there's no `master` branch, instead there's a `base` branch and `mobile` and `web` are **never** merged into `base`.

What do you think? I like the second approach as long as all the team members stick to the rules. I'll be the responsible to review all the pull requests to the remote repository, so I can verify that all the changes are ok.

Comment: It's been a minute since this question was asked. Your second approach makes sense and I am curious to know if it worked out for you?
Along with the above-mentioned solution, I would suggest for anyone reading this to use generators to make it simpler.
Generators like [feathers-plus](https://generator.feathers-plus.com/get-started/#comparing-cli-plus-to-feathersjs-cli) help generate files using a JSON-schema that can live in your `base` branch and then be used to generate files for `mobile` and `web`. With feathers-plus's round trip generation(regenerating files) means that you can make change